# What is the technology behind OpenOffice.org Anywhere

Tags: web-applications, openoffice.org

I able to launch open office through web browser, even I do not have a copy of open office.

http://www.ooanywhere.com/

May I know what is the technology behind?

(Although the launched open office is quite slow and not responsive)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our service is based on the following technologies:

- Linux based machines running in the cloud (datacenter is located in the eastern US and it may indeed be slower for distant locations);
- for remote access we're using open source NX server from [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com);
- on the client side we're running custom-built Java Applet which talks to our servers via SSH;

Let us know if you want to know something more.

Comment: Wow! Answer from ooanywhere owner! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On the client side, a Java applet is used. The Java applet creates a new Frame, that appears on the client computer.

The Java client applications then uses a screen sharing protocol (I think something X tunnelling) to display the interface to you.

The server is a Linux machine, that launches OOo for you, the display beeing deported to your client machine.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the FAQ, I would assume it uses some form of screen sharing protocol, such as VNC.